# SharePoint Email Notification set up

Tags: email, outgoing-email, nintex

I have set up our outgoing E-mail settings to `sharepoint-noreply@test.com` and every-time we set up a Workflow users will receive notification from this email address.

Is there anyway I can change the email address based on the list name?

For example: If I want to set up Workflow to send an email to HR instead of `SharePoint-norply@test.com` it say something like `SharePointHR@test.com`

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify the To/From for the emails, the SharePoint version, and if SharePoint Online. (If Online, then Flow might be an option.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the From address of the workflow generated email, then no. You could add a link in the email with the address... "Please reply to hr@contoso.com".

Setting the To is part of the workflow dialog box:

[image]

Comment: thanks Mike, we are using Nintex WF and not a SP designer, is there anyway we can do this with Nintex?

Comment: I don't use Nintex, but I would assume so.